# Does alcohol give bonus to will saves against fear?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Me and my friend were arguing regarding the effects of alcohol and i wanted to ask here to clarify. Are there any positive effects to being intoxicated?

Comment: I am looking for advantages of drinking alcohol rather than penalties

Comment: We really don’t need two separate questions on the subject; any rules source that covers the effects of alcohol will cover both benefits and penalties. I have edited the other question to be slightly broader, which shouldn’t change answers in the least since again, any source that addresses one side of the coin is also going to address the other.